# Selected value for JSP drop down

Tags: java, jsp

In my JSP page i'm using a popup to add new precipitants to the dropdown list. its working fine but problem is if i add one, the dorpdown shows "Add New" instead of "--Please Select--"

This is what i tried later

`<c:if test="${listop.precipitants eq listop.precipant}">Selected </c:if>`

and getting `Unterminated <form:option tag` exception

here is my controller code

```
    map.put("precipitantdroplist", bioprofileservice.listPrecipitantdrop());
    map.put("Precipitantdropfam", new Precipitantsdrop());
```

and in JSP

```
<form:select  path="precipant" id="precipant" onchange="showpopup(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.form,'Newprecipant?#login_form3');">
 <form:option value="">--Please Select--</form:option>
 <c:if test="${!empty precipitantdroplist}">
                <c:forEach items="${precipitantdroplist}" var="listop">
                <form:option value="${listop.precipitants}" <c:if test="${listop.precipitants eq listop.precipant}">Selected </c:if>>${listop.precipitants}</form:option>       
                </c:forEach>
          </c:if>
 <form:option value="">-----------------------</form:option>
                <form:option value="Add New">Add New</form:option>
                <form:option value="removeP">Remove</form:option>
  </form:select>
```

<-------- edited here---------->

this is how my drop down look like

[image]

once i click "Add New" its look like this, but i want "--Please Select--" instead "Add New" (see the image below)
[image]

after i add "meme" my dropdown look like this

[image]

but i want like this
[image]

Comment: seriously suggest you use jquery and just add a select listener to the id #precipant

Comment: @ScaryWombat can you show me how to do that?

Comment: @user20432 try my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, modify if condition according to yours if required.

```
    <form:select  name="precipant" path="precipant" id="precipant" onchange="showpopup(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value,this.form,'Newprecipant?#login_form3');">
 <form:option value="" selected="selected">--Please Select--</form:option> 

    <c:forEach items="${precipitantdroplist}" var="listop">
            <c:if test="${listop.precipitants eq listop.precipant}">
                <option value="${listop.precipitants}">${listop.precipitants}</option>
            </c:if>
            <c:if test="${listop.precipitants != listop.precipant}">
                <option value="${listop.precipitants}">${listop.precipitants}</option>
            </c:if>
    </c:forEach>

    <form:option value="">-----------------------</form:option>
    <form:option value="Add New">Add New</form:option>
    <form:option value="removeP">Remove</form:option>
</form:select>
```

or register the handler for the dropdown like this,

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $("#precipant").change(function() {
            $('select[name^="precipant"] option:selected').attr("selected",null);
            $('select[name^="precipant"] option[value="Please Select"]').attr("selected","selected");
        });

    });

    </script>
```

Comment: thanx but it always shows last value i add not "--Please Select--"

Comment: @user20432 can you elaborate and also check this condition, 

`<c:if test="${listop.precipitants eq listop.precipant}">`, the right side should contain only one value which you have selected, what is `listop.precipant`

Comment: `precipitants`is the only thing in my table forget about `precipant` 
what i want is once i add a new item, drop down should show  "--Please Select--"

with your code i modified like this

`<c:if test="${listop.precipitants eq listop.precipitants}">`

but it always shows last value i added

Comment: @user20432 questin is getting misunderstood here, please ass more details as what value you want to show in dropdown and in which all scenarios, like when u open a popup, or after adding one, now what.